# Terraform plan fails on data elements incorrectly claiming they don't exist

Tags: azure, terraform

I am running Terraform v0.12.16 on mac os.  I have a terraform file referencing data lookups for azure:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=1.37.0"
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "tfstate"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

/* Pull in shared resources */
data "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {
  name = "Development"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "uat" {
  name = "UAT"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "staging" {
  name = "Staging"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "prod" {
  name = "Production"
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "containerRegistryAU"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.dev.name
}
```

When I run a terraform plan I get:

```
terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

random_integer.ri: Refreshing state... [id=44293]
data.azurerm_dns_zone.staging_ynomia_com: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_resource_group.dev: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_resource_group.staging: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_dns_zone.uat_ynomia_com: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_resource_group.prod: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_resource_group.uat: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_dns_zone.dev_ynomia_com: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_dns_zone.ynomia_com: Refreshing state...

Error: Error: Resource Group "Development" was not found

  on _main.tf line 27, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "dev":
  27: data "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {



Error: Error: Resource Group "UAT" was not found

  on _main.tf line 31, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "uat":
  31: data "azurerm_resource_group" "uat" {



Error: Error: Resource Group "Staging" was not found

  on _main.tf line 35, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "staging":
  35: data "azurerm_resource_group" "staging" {



Error: Error: Resource Group "Production" was not found

  on _main.tf line 39, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "prod":
  39: data "azurerm_resource_group" "prod" {



Error: Error: DNS Zone "ynomia.com" was not found

  on _main.tf line 138, in data "azurerm_dns_zone" "ynomia_com":
 138: data "azurerm_dns_zone" "ynomia_com" {



Error: Error: DNS Zone "dev.ynomia.com" was not found

  on _main.tf line 142, in data "azurerm_dns_zone" "dev_ynomia_com":
 142: data "azurerm_dns_zone" "dev_ynomia_com" {



Error: Error: DNS Zone "uat.ynomia.com" was not found

  on _main.tf line 146, in data "azurerm_dns_zone" "uat_ynomia_com":
 146: data "azurerm_dns_zone" "uat_ynomia_com" {



Error: Error: DNS Zone "staging.ynomia.com" was not found

  on _main.tf line 150, in data "azurerm_dns_zone" "staging_ynomia_com":
 150: data "azurerm_dns_zone" "staging_ynomia_com" {
```

However I know these resources exist:
[image: Azure portal showing my resource groups]

This has been working for months so I'm perplexed as to why it's suddenly failing.  How do I debug what's going on here?

Comment: Are these resource groups all in the same Azure subscription? Looks like your terraform is authenticating to the incorrect subscription...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, the possible reason is that you use the subscription which the local Azure CLI current used, but it's not the right subscription that you want to use.

So you need to find the right subscription which your resource groups in. Then change the Terraform provider like this:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=1.37.0"

  subscription_id = "your_subscription_id"
  tenant_id = "your_tenant_id"
}
```

It will get the resource groups from the subscription and tenant which you need to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm on terraform 1.0.1 and making sure I had the correct subscription did the trick for me.